# Set the value to drop down list using Javascript and get that value in C#

Tags: c#, javascript

```
    function SetDropDownValue() {
            var opt = document.createElement("option");
            opt.text = "New Value";
            opt.value = "New Value";
            document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList.ClientID%>').options.add(opt);
            document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList.ClientID%>').value = val;
    }
```

The above coding works good for me, The new value append to the drop down list while clicking the button. Then i want to get the drop down value in my code behind(C#). It not working in C#.

```
    string res = DropDownList.SelectedValue;
```

In the C# coding displays only empty string ("").

How can i get the dropdown selected value?

Comment: Is this WebForms? Otherwise you'd have to post the value of the select to your server side application to handle your request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the `html` but not the `ViewState` of the `DropDownList` that is why you are not getting in asp.net server side `code`. You can add the value in some hidden field and use that on server side.

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnDDL" runat="server" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function SetDropDownValue() {
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.text = "New Value";
    opt.value = "New Value";
    document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList.ClientID%>').options.add(opt);
    document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList.ClientID%>').value = val;
    document.getElementById('<%=hdnDDL.ClientID%>').value = val;
}
```

**Code behind**

```
string optionValue = hdnDDL.Value;
```